# How to pass the Heroku-assigned port for CI testing a SailsJS app

Tags: node.js, heroku, continuous-integration, mocha.js, sails.js

I am trying to configure a Heroku pipeline to run a NodeJS / SailsJS application's Mocha tests successfully before deploying the app to production.

The test run fails because the application is not aware of the port that Heroku has randomly assigned (or so it seems). During one of the tests, the test runner tries to fetch a CSRF token, which it cannot. Locally, it works without a problem.

I tried to pass the correct port in the `package.json` file, via the following line:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --port process.env.PORT --timeout 15000 --config=test/mocharc.json --node-env=test --exit test/suites/**.js",
```

but unfortunately, this did not work.

Does anyone know how to pass the Heroku-assigned port to Mocha...?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was nót to try to set the PORT, since it is automatically set by Heroku.

In the application, the PORT is available via:

```
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT,
```

The tests work now.